# Pandas, fillin the empty time-series with a charging battery pattern

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series, simulation

I want to simulate battery charging data.

Imagine there is a battery with a constant capacity. e.g. 30000, in the real world a person will charge it at random times at 18:00-18:30, so sometimes the he starts at 18:29 some times start at 18:00, so the half hourly value will be varied by the start charging time. But the total amount won't be changed.

```
index   value
0   2021-01-01 00:00:00 0
1   2021-01-01 00:30:00 0
2   2021-01-01 01:00:00 0
3   2021-01-01 01:30:00 0
4   2021-01-01 02:00:00 0
... ... ...
995 2021-01-21 17:30:00 0
996 2021-01-21 18:00:00 0
997 2021-01-21 18:30:00 0
998 2021-01-21 19:00:00 0
999 2021-01-21 19:30:00 0
1000    2021-01-21 20:00:00 0
```

So, if the charging speed is 5000 per half hour, it sometimes likes:`[10,5000,5000,5000,5000,5000,4990]`, and sometimes `[2500,5000,5000,5000,5000,2500]`.
And I want to generate such a pattern and insert it into a given time.

```
index   value
0   2021-01-01 00:00:00 0
1   2021-01-01 00:30:00 0
2   2021-01-01 01:00:00 0
3   2021-01-01 01:30:00 0
4   2021-01-01 02:00:00 0
... ... ...
995 2021-01-21 17:30:00 0
996 2021-01-21 18:00:00 2500
997 2021-01-21 18:30:00 5000
998 2021-01-21 19:00:00 5000
999 2021-01-21 19:30:00 5000
1000    2021-01-21 20:00:00 5000
1001    2021-01-01 20:30:00 2500
1002    2021-01-01 21:00:00 0
```

Assume he charging around the time defined by `start` parameter. If the `start` is '2021-01-01 18:00' it will start charging between 18:00 to 18:30.
The function I want:

```py
def insertPattern(emptyTimeseriesDF, capacity, speed, start) :
    
    return dfWithInsertedPattern
```

Empty ts generated by:

```
index = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2021,1,1), periods=1000, freq='30min')
columns = ['value']

df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
df = df.fillna(0)
df = df.reset_index()
df
```